# ESS does not find Rterm.exe on windows

Tags: emacs, ess

I installed R in a directory called "X:\alphaAndOmega\R\R". So Rterm.exe (32-Bit version) is located in "X:\alphaAndOmega\R\R\bin\i386". I know that it's not a 'standard R-directory' and that "standard R-directories", like R-3.0.0 are easily recognized by ESS (at least if I add them to my PATH variable in Windows).

I tried customizing my .emacs file in a way, that ESS would look for Rterm.exe in my non-standard directory, but I wasn't able to do so. I'm absolutely new to emacs and i tried playing around wird some of the following commands:

`inferior-R-program-name` and `ess-rterm-version-paths`

But I failed. ESS doesn't find anything.

I use emacs 24.3.1, ESS 13.05 and R 2.15. At the moment my .emacs file contains just one line, so that shouldn't be a problem:

`(require 'ess-site)`

What can I do to make ESS find my Rterm.exe?

Answer (score 7):

There really only is one configuration setting in `ess-site.el`; I have used that one in the past.  Here it is from `ess-site.el` but note that it is commented-out:

```
;; If you wish to call other versions of R on a Unix system, ESS 
;; should auto-detect other versions of R, according to matches to the   
;; variable `ess-r-versions' as described in its docstring.  Consider   
;; changing that variable rather than changing inferior-R-program-name  
;; if your version of R is not already auto-detected.                  
;;(setq-default inferior-R-program-name "R")        ; unix systems    
;;(setq-default inferior-R-program-name "Rterm")    ; MS Windows, see below for path
;;(setq-default inferior-R-program-name "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.5.0\\bin\\Rterm.exe")
```

And I just checked on my work machine, and there `Rterm.exe` is found by default from the `$PATH`.  I do use the [Emacs/ESS/AucTeX bundle by Vincent Goulet](http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/windows/) which I can wholeheartedly recommend as "it just works."

Answer (score 3):

To point ESS to a non-standard R-directory, set the variable `ess-directory-containing-R`. (This handy variable is a relatively recent feature.) Quoting from [the ESS manual](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html):

> Changes/New Features in 12.09:
>
> ESS[R]: On Windows, there is now a new customizable variable
>   (currently called ess-directory-containing-R) to tell ESS where to
>   look for the Rterm.exe executables. The name of the variable and the
>   values it can take are both in beta and subject to change. Prior to
>   this variable, ESS searched only in the default installation
>   directory. Setting this variable now tells ESS how to find Rterm.exe
>   executables when they are installed somewhere else.

If I recall correctly, this needs to be done before loading `ess-site.el`; in any case that's what I have in my .emacs file, which does a fine job of finding all of my R versions, which are all stored under `"C:/R/"`:

```
(setq ess-directory-containing-R "c:")
;; Add to list of prefixes recognized by ESS. 
;; Matching versions will appear after doing M-x R <TAB> <TAB> 
(setq ess-r-versions '("R-1" "R-2" "R-3" "R-current" "R-devel" "R-patched"))
(load "C:/Program Files/GNU Emacs 23.3/site-lisp/ess/lisp/ess-site.el")

;; Set default R version, (i.e. the one launched by typing M-x R <RET>)
(setq inferior-R-program-name "c:/R/R-current/bin/i386/Rterm.exe")
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the ess-directory-containing-R variable did not work when I had this problem.  Further, when I did a 'describe-variable' on it, on another machine which had a properly working ess-emacs on it, the value was nil, so I don't think that's right.

What DID work is setting the PATH variable in the Windows environment to point to the directory that Rterm.exe lives in, and then restarting emacs.

Comment: I did this on windows 10 using spacemacs without changing any .el file.

Answer (score 0):

With a default install of ESS (currently 17.11) and R (3.4.4) on Windows, running M-x `R` tries to execute Rterm.exe in your `exec-path` and will fail if it is not found there. The automatically generated runners should be used instead eg. M-x `R-3.4.4-64bit` or simply M-x `R-newest`.

To use a non-standard R location set `ess-directory-containing-R` to the base directory to search for R installations. This needs to be done before `ess-site` is loaded so might require restarting emacs after updating your init file. This will allow the automatically generated runners to be created.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the variable `ess-directory-containing-R` needs some care with 
Vincent Goulet's distribution for Windows, referred to in Dirk's answer. I have been using that for the best part of two decades. Below is an excerpt from my "hints" file about the handling of this.

If R is installed in a non-standard place, ESS needs to be told were to look
for by setting variable `ess-directory-containing-R` to the root of the tree
were the various versions of R reside. The issue is that "site-start.el" is executed before user's ".emacs" (see section "The Emacs Initialization File" of the Emacs manual), so just setting `ess-directory-containing-R` in ".emacs" will not do. I am reluctant to just load "site-start.el" a second time, as in Josh's answer.

If the various R versions are installed under "c:/myPrograms/R/",
then the setting of the variable should be "c:/myPrograms" (i.e. without the
trailing "/R"). Since this needs to be done before loading ESS, I add the following line to V. Goulet's site file, 
"path\to\emacs\share\emacs\site-lisp\site-start.el",

```
(setq ess-directory-containing-R "c:/myPrograms")
```

just before it loads ESS, i.e. just before the following lines in the file:

```
   ;; Load ESS.
   (require 'ess-site)
```